# MVC4 and dropdown using onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've searched several posts on this and the methods all would normally work, however...
I'm in an environment where we use 3 different servers (Dev, UAT and Prod).  All 3 have differing URL structures:

```
http://dev.com/myusername/applicationname (Dev)
http://uat.com/applicationname (UAT)
http://prod.com/applicationname (Prod)
```

The issue that I'm having is when I try to use a dropdown I'm having problems getting the url right.  The issue is when I use the following code to populate my dropdown:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Owners", ViewData["Owners"] as SelectList, new { onchange = "document.location.href='/Builds/' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" })
```

It handles the event just fine, but produces a URL of:
http://dev.com/Builds/value.  I need it to be http://dev.com/myusername/application/Builds/value.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the base uri then append your stuff to that:

```
 string baseUrl = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + 
    Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/";
```

Note that the trim is there because it may or may not end with the trailing slash depending on where it is hosted (root or sub directory)

You might also be able to use

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Builds/")
```

This might also work:

```
@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)@Url.Content("~/Builds/")
```

Comment: Putting the baseUrl in the controller and adding it to the list item worked like a champ!  Thanks!